# How to get all iteration paths for the selected project in TFS programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

Code for getting TFS projects in combobox:

```
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(_tfs.Uri);
        var vsStore = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var projects = vsStore.GetItems("$/" + _selectedTeamProject.Name + "/*");
        ClearProjectItems();
        foreach (var project in projects.Items)
        {
            var projectItem = project.ServerItem.Replace("$/" + _selectedTeamProject.Name + "/", "");
            cmbProjects.Items.Add(projectItem);
        }
```

Now, I want to get the iteration paths for the selected project in TFS programatically. The Iteration paths will be binded in another combobox.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Common Structure service.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-9-get-areaiteration-programmatically/

Comment: The link explains about adding the node. But, i need to display the iteration paths for the selected project.

Comment: Changed link to link from first paragraph of old link 